# How do I unserialize a php-serialize value in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am able to send the php serialized value in js file.But i couldnt unserialise the value in js. Is that possible to unserialize the php value using js .Can anyone help me out..

php file:

```
$grades_value = base64_encode(serialize($form_values['grades']));
```

Comment: Are you using `json_encode()` method of php to serialize the data? if so you have to unserialize using the js method of `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: To base64 decode: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding I'd also suggest you use `json_encode()` instead of `serialize()` as JS can then deserialise the JSON using: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: You can't unless you're prepared to write an entire PHP unserialiser in Javascript.  You should instead use a format that both PHP and Javascript can handle easily such as json.  Just json_encode() your output in the PHP script instead of serialize() it.

Comment: Got the soln .. Thank u GordonM